# Confused on how to use grant statement to make another login with password

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

```
create login sea with password = 'Atlantic-ocean';
```

A `GRANT` statement to execute if we allow the above 'sea'
login to create another login called 'jellyfish' with a password 'Jelly-fish'.

```
create user jellyfish for login sea; 
grant alter user jellyfish
    with password = 'Jelly-fish';
```

> msg 33234 parameter password cannot be provided for users that cannot
>   authenticate in a database.